# Update alias column base on name column

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to update an "alias" column based on a "name" column on a MySQL database? The alias column is now empty and I need to populate it this way:

```
Name                                Alias
United Nations                      united-nations
World Health Organization           world-health-organization
Ministre des Affaires étrangères    ministre-des-affaires-etrangeres
Gobierno de España                  gobierno-de-espana
```

The this is to change all to lowercase, remove all special characters (like ñ, ó, ö etc...) and change spaces to hyphens. Is it possible?

Thank you for the help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `replace()` and `lower()` do what you want:

```
update t
  set alias = replace(lower(name), ' ', '-');
```

You appear to also want to change the accented characters to ASCII, so:

```
update t
  set alias = convert(replace(lower(name), ' ', '-') using latin1);
```

Comment: Thank you. So I first need to copy the Name column to the Alias column and then convert the alias column with that operation?

Comment: If you use `alias = ...` instead of `name = ...` in Gordon's update statement above, it will copy the modified value to the `alias` column.

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks... it gives me this error: An alias was previously found. (near "=" at position 42)

Comment: @eera5607: I just noticed Gordon's UPDATE statement is incorrect. I'll offer to edit it (pardon me Gordon), but you should be able to write basic UPDATE syntax without help, even if you have look it up in reference documentation.

Comment: @BillKarwin Thank you and sorry, yes I'm very new to this. It is not my field I'm doing it as hobby. It worked almost perfectly but the letters with accents (é, ó etc...) kept them...

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Gordon Linoff that Bill Karwin edited worked fine but this is and additional step to remove all special characters in my case.

```
update t set alias = replace(alias, "á", "a");
update t set alias = replace(alias, "é", "e");
update t set alias = replace(alias, "í", "i");
update t set alias = replace(alias, "ó", "o");
update t set alias = replace(alias, "ú", "u");
update t set alias = replace(alias, "Á", "A");
update t set alias = replace(alias, "É", "E");
update t set alias = replace(alias, "Í", "I");
update t set alias = replace(alias, "Ó", "O");
update t set alias = replace(alias, "Ú", "U");
update t set alias = replace(alias, "ñ", "n");
update t set alias = replace(alias, "Ñ", "N");
```

Thanks!